# How to write the filename and rowcount in a csv in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've been trying to make a CSV from a big list of another CSVs and here's the deal: I want to get the names of these CSV files and put them in the CSV that I want to create, plus, I also need the row count from the CSV files that I'm getting the names of, here's what I've tried so far:

```
def getRegisters(file):
    results = pd.read_csv(file, header = None, error_bad_lines= False, sep = '\t', low_memory = False)
    print(len(results))
    return len(results)
path = "C:/Users/gdldieca/Desktop/TESTSFORPANW/New folder"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
with open("C:/Users/gdldieca/Desktop/TESTSFORPANW/New folder/FilesNames.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '\t')
    writer.writerow(("File", "Rows"))
    for names in dirs:
        sfile = getRegisters("C:/Users/gdldieca/Desktop/TESTSFORPANW/New folder/" + str(names))
        writer.writerow((names, sfile))
```

However I can't seem to get the files row count even tho Pandas actually returns it. I'm getting this error:

```
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int
```

The final result would be something like this written into the CSV

```
File1 90
File2 10
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `names` is a string so you don't have to use `str()`. And you could use `path + '/' + names` to create path. OR even better `os.path.join(path, names)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using pandas , I think you can use also for make a csv file with all values that you need..Here an alternative

```
import os
import pandas as pd

directory='D:\\MY\\PATH\\ALLCSVFILE\\'
#create a list for add all
rows_list = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
         file=os.path.join(directory, filename)
         df=pd.read_csv(file)
         #Count rows
         rowcount=len(df.index)
         new_row = {'namefile':filename, 'count':rowcount}
         rows_list.append(new_row)

#pass list to dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
print(df1)
df1.to_csv('test.csv', sep=',')
```

result :
[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! This was actually what I was looking for.